# Is there something akin to SetupGetSequence in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In `Moq`, I know that there is `SetupSequence` for setting sequential usage of a function and there is `SetupGet` for setting a value for a property.

However I need to set a property in a sequential way.

Is there a way for setting up sequential get in `Moq`?

Note: I did not write the interface or the service which I am mocking, therefore I cannot change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sequencing return values with `SetupSequence` works for property getters as well :

```
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.PropertyName).Returns(1).Returns(2).Returns(3);
```

*Note:* you can use `Setup` instead of `SetupGet`, because Moq checks whether the body of given lambda expression is a property and calls `SetupGet` internally [[Source Code]](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Mock.cs#L471). So the only benefit you have is skipping this internal check.